# EXCEPT & INTERSECT: Purpose of Passive Projection in Logical Plan

Tags: sql-server, optimization, database-internals, except

The following EXCEPT query produces a logical plan with a seemingly purposeless projection. This also occurs for INTERSECT.

What is the purpose of the projection? e.g. Is there a different EXCEPT query where the outer projection would specify something?

Query:

```
use AdventureWorks2017

select p.ProductId
from Production.Product as p
except
select pinv.ProductID
from Production.ProductInventory as pinv
option (recompile, querytraceon 8605, querytraceon 3604)
```

Converted Tree:

```
    LogOp_Select

        LogOp_GbAgg OUT(QCOL: [p].ProductID,) BY(QCOL: [p].ProductID,)

            LogOp_Project -- << ?? PASSIVE PROJECTION ??

                LogOp_Project

                    LogOp_Get TBL: Production.Product(alias TBL: p) Production.Product TableID=482100758 TableReferenceID=0 IsRow: COL: IsBaseRow1000 

                    AncOp_PrjList 

                AncOp_PrjList 

            AncOp_PrjList 

        ScaOp_Exists 

            LogOp_Select

                LogOp_Project

                    LogOp_Get TBL: Production.ProductInventory(alias TBL: pinv) Production.ProductInventory TableID=914102297 TableReferenceID=0 IsRow: COL: IsBaseRow1001 

                    AncOp_PrjList 

                ScaOp_Comp x_cmpEq

                    ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [p].ProductID

                    ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [pinv].ProductID
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are various things we do inside the query optimizer that don't really have a reason that we can explain externally.  The projects you see in the optimizer eventually get rewritten at the end of the optimizer to "flatten" the expressions.  So, the optimizer has things in the search that are part of how the code is implemented that may introduce extra projects that don't really do anything functionally but do allow us to stitch things together where one subtree was created in one part of the optimizer but is used later in a place where it was not originally intended.  There are some physical implementation details that can cause this to happen.  None of them matter for users in terms of plan quality (in almost any case - we have done work to make these not matter in the search).

So, I'd just wave my hand and say "you don't need to see his identification.  He can go about his business.  Move along" ;).

Answer (score 11):

I don't have a fully satisfying answer to this, but `DISTINCT` is translated to a project plus group-by aggregate.

Both [`EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) come with an implied `DISTINCT` on the first table expression. It is this `DISTINCT` that results in the 'blank' project in the tree. It is harmless.

If you write a `DISTINCT` as the equivalent `GROUP BY`, you don't see the blank project. The project appears after the aggregate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.ProductID
FROM Production.Product AS P
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 3604, QUERYTRACEON 8605);
```

```
LogOp_GbAgg OUT(QCOL: [P].ProductID,) BY(QCOL: [P].ProductID,)
    LogOp_Project
        LogOp_Project QCOL: [P].ProductID
            LogOp_Get TBL: Production.Product(alias TBL: P)
            AncOp_PrjList 
        AncOp_PrjList 
    AncOp_PrjList
```

```
SELECT P.ProductID
FROM Production.Product AS P
GROUP BY p.ProductID
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 3604, QUERYTRACEON 8605);
```

```
LogOp_Project QCOL: [P].ProductID
    LogOp_GbAgg OUT(QCOL: [P].ProductID,) BY(QCOL: [P].ProductID,)
        LogOp_Project
            LogOp_Get TBL: Production.Product(alias TBL: P)
            AncOp_PrjList 
        AncOp_PrjList 
    AncOp_PrjList
```

Comment: I did indeed do a repro with group by, just to see if the blank project appeared (which as you've shown, doesn't).

This was mainly a point of curiosity...  no "production" goal here... my Covid downtime has resulted in me killing days by creating logical plan repros for as much of the T/SQL reference as I can get through; In this case, I thought there may be a variation of EXCEPT/INTERSECT where the projection would be 'used', and hence this manifestation was simply a placeholder, to be used in some circumstance. But it seems not.

Comment: Yeah we all have some extra COVID time :) Please accept Conor's answer. It's not every day the lead architect of the query optimizer answers your quesion.

Comment: Duly done, and a very big tip 'o the hat to Conor